# Openstack Nova API: live update

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova

I need to write a service that connects to Nova API and is instantly informed about any update in tenant's port or VM changes. Is this somehow possible?

I know how to do this with Kubernetes (`/api/v1/watch/services`) but were unable to find how to do this with Nova API.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to write a service that connects to Nova API and is instantly informed about any update in tenant's port or VM changes. Is this somehow possible?

Most OpenStack services emit event notifications via the message bus (often, but not always, RabbitMQ).  The documentaiton for Nova notifications can be found [here](https://docs.openstack.org/developer/nova/notifications.html).

You would need to write a client that connects to the message bus and subscribes to the appropriate notifications.

Comment: thanks, but I don't have access to RabbitMQ ports :-(